# I wanted to store the values of a checkbox in the firestore database by calling a function in each seat i click

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a hard time storing value for each seat that i click.
i tried calling a function in each html label and get the value for each seat and store it into the firestore database. I dont want to make 700 variables for each seat. Is there any way that i can only call a function that specifically saves THAT seat that i checked and stores it in the database

[image: here is the Seat Reservation map that i made]

```js
  const seat = document.querySelector("#seat:checked").value;
 
     db.collection("Users").doc(email_id).collection("SeatReservation").doc().set({
        reserved: seat

 })
 .then(function() {
  console.log("Document successfully written!");
        window.alert("Sent");
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
 });
}
```

```html
<li class="seat">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3W" value="W3"/>
    <label onClick="reserve();" for="3W">3</label>
</li>
```

Comment: It looks like you can only query seats reserved for a particular user ID.  I'm trying to understand your question.  Are you wanting to run a single query to return the state of all seats?

Comment: each seat has a value for example seat W1 has a value of W1 im trying to save that value to the database . but is there any way of saving each value of each seat by only calling one function and getting that value from one ID?

Comment: You could have a single document, which you can get / update with the seats and their values.  Without the bigger picture, it's difficult to work out what you're trying to achieve.  I'm imagining that you're allocating seats for events.  If that's the case, I could help you with a data model which would facilitate that.  I'm confused as to why you're wanting to store the value of seat W1 as W1.  Surely, you want to know if the seat is reserved or not?

Comment: im still bainging my head over this . Maybe i dont need to store anything, is there anyway that a user can click a seat that highlights it through an user page and share the page for the customer so that they can see what seats are reserved?

Comment: This sounds entirely possible.  However, without further details of your use case, it's really hard to propose a solution.  This could turn into a long conversation here and I'm not sure that this is the best place for it.  Feel free to reach out to me offline

Comment: where can i contact you sir?